# When I lock the screen while the app I created is running, it does not ask for the password and I can see the app

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter app, but something unexpected is happening after testing it on a real device. On the actual device, when the screen is locked, it is set to ask for the passcode. However, when I lock the app I created while it is running, it does not ask for the password and I can see the app. I would like the password lock to be activated when I press the power button and then press the power button again. How can I do this?

Chrome apps, for example, properly apply a password lock when the power button is pressed. Only my app does not lock.

Comment: Are you running on debug or release mode?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I tried to install from apk but no luck.
However, I solved the problem in another way.
In the AndroidManifest.xml file, I had set "android:showWhenLocked" to "true". I changed it to "false" and now it locks.
I was stupid to copy someone else's code without understanding it, sorry.
Thank you very much.